# Why does most software break or refuse to continue immediately if the folder where their data is stored is not available?

Tags: error-handling, file-storage

Most software creates a directory (usually in `~/Library` or `~/Library/Application Support` in MacOS) to store user preferences, browser history, etc. Most software attempts to create their data directory immediately upon launch and will either crash or refuse to continue if the directory cannot be created.

For example, if I create a *file* called `~/Library/Application Support/Google`, then Google Chrome will be unable to access or create a directory there, because the name is already taken by a non directory. This will cause Google Chrome to immediately 'quit unexpectedly'. If I do the equivalent to Firefox, a message will say that an 'unexpected error has prevented changes from being saved' and will have to quit.

Why would changes have to be saved in software so importantly that the software will break if it cannot? Do they really need to create a bunch of files to render a webpage at a URL? I do not see any way were *saving data* is critical to the immediate execution of the app. The worst that should happen is all the apps configuration and data should reset as soon as it quits.

Why is it common for apps to **break immediately** if no data saving directory is available?

Comment: **Thought experiment:** how useful is a piece of software if it cannot save changes to its state?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If the software in question is a browser, as useful as a browser that is always in private or incognito mode

Comment: I think your real question is "How can I so easily break Chrome?"

Comment: And I think the answer to that question is "Because Google never anticipated someone stomping all over their Application Support folder in this manner."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Chrome was just an example of an app that will break if I make its folder unavailable

Comment: In Chrome's specific case, the answer is most likely "if we can't even make our temporary folder available, something has gone horribly wrong, and we're giving up."

Comment: Software is designed with certain assumptions in mind, like the assumption that it will be able to use a specific directory on disk. I'm willing to bet that assumption is correct 99.999% of the time, so from Google's perspective, it's not an issue worth spending time on.

Comment: Because it is unexpected, and continuing to execute in that case can just create more problems. It could be indicative of a more serious problem, a security threat, a misconfiguration, or even a hardware problem. Any attempt to continue execution may work, may behave sporadically, crash out later (with an error that does not indicate the root problem), or even give some malicious process access to data it shouldn't have access to.

Comment: I think 1201ProgramAlarm has hit the nail on the head.  If the software can't create its directory and files with the permissions it chooses, then they may have entirely inappropriate permissions resulting in unauthorized disclosure of information.  For example, SSH checks the permissions on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and errors if you much with it.

Comment: Most software is lacking in robustness. If a robust program is unable to store its data in the preferred directory ~/Library, it could make a secondary directory such as ~/Library2.

Comment: @cwallach how many `~/LibraryN`s should you try before you conclude that you can't create any directories? And how do you reconcile `~/Library2` that happened during last week's network slowdown with this week's `~/Library5`, with the original `~/Library` that's available again now that Jim plugged that cable back in?

Comment: @RobertHarvey or "Google don't care if people *deliberatly* break *their* Chrome install"

Comment: Because sometimes it's better to quit immediately (and give a precise reason why, so it can be addressed) rather than to keep going and let you know 3 months later that a lot of stuff was lost and you could have avoided that.

Comment: @haylem It could alert the user that changes cannot be saved and continue instead of quitting

Comment: @user16217248: it could, but it would inherently be a less safe user experience. What you want would favor practicality at the cost of a potential data loss. It's not something are generally super keen with.

Comment: @cwallach: And having created ~/Library2, in which to store preference and stuff, how would Chrome - or any other program - know to use that location in future, given that such a "preference" would be stored *in* ~/Library2!  The program has to start somewhere. 
(Don't mention the Registry)

Comment: @Phill W.  Lets think about this.  The program can first check ~/Library. If the config is not present then check ~/Library2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C programming, we have this notion of *undefined behavior.*

It means that, if you write code that creates situations that are not defined by the language standard, anything can happen.  The program could crash, it could corrupt memory, it could accidentally call `fireMissiles()`.  Or, it could exhibit reasonable behavior.  There's no way to be sure, once you enter the "undefined behavior" space.

Hence, the simple assumption that a program usually makes that it can access the disk, not an unreasonable assumption in most cases.  Most programs will give up if the computer they're running on cannot meet this simple requirement.  Continuing to run a program when a machine has been perceived to be compromised in some way can cause all sorts of unforseen problems.

Chrome doesn't make the guarantee that it doesn't save any kind of state at all in incognito mode.  It only makes certain assertions about your privacy.  Remembering the window location when you close the program doesn't have anything to do with your privacy, and I'm sure there are other examples that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that the *"quit unexpectedly"* behavior that you see is caused by an "unhandled exception."  Many (non-web ...) programming contexts will also do this if an exception drifts all the way to the top without being caught.

Unfortunately, lots of developers write their software on "super-powerful machines," where "nothing ever goes wrong," and issues like these literally never occur to them. They don't *mean* it ...

---

Which is, for example, why I counsel mobile developers to go buy a mobile phone in the checkout-line of their supermarket, and to make sure that their precious application will actually run on *that,* instead of their "IPhone 135 with 65,536GB of memory."

Comment: Well, sure, but could Google have anticipated that someone would change their Application Support folder to a *file?*  Google has very talented people working for them, but I'm pretty sure none of them are clairvoyant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Testing the return value of the functions used to access the Application Support folder would exhaustively handle errors, including my putting a file there, and then they should handle the error gracefully like alerting the user that changes will not be saved instead of just letting the app crash

Comment: @user16217248 You assume that the directory is only used for user configuration purposes. You assume that terminating the program is not graceful. You even seem to assume that terminating the program is unintentional, which very well might be. I think your question is interesting, but it stems from the incorrect premise that a program should never be terminated and should handle all possible edge cases at all cost, which just doesn't work in practice.

Comment: @user16217248 There are user errors in the category "You've broken your Mac". If you do that, my app will show an alert if you're lucky and exit, but fixing it is your problem. Take your Mac to your admin or to an Apple Store or to your nephew who is good with computers, but not to me. The whole Library folder is hidden. If you go into hidden folders, you're on your own.